# Replace multiple strings and numbers from multiple columns with NaN in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I have a following dataframe, I would like to clean data by replacing multiple strings and numbers into `NaN`s: ie. `68, Tardeo Road` and `0` from `state`, `567` from `dept`, and `#ERROR!` and `123` from `phonenumber`:

```
   id                                state                          dept  \
0   1                            Abu Dhabi                   {Marketing}   
1   2                                   MO                       {Other}   
2   3                      68, Tardeo Road           {"Human Resources"}   
3   4  National Capital Territory of Delhi           {"Human Resources"}   
4   5                        Aargau Canton                   {Marketing}   
5   6                        Aargau Canton                           567   
6  18                                   NB  {"Finance & Administration"}   
7  19                                    0                       {Sales}   
8  20                            Abu Dhabi           {"Human Resources"}   
9  21                               Aargau  {"Finance & Administration"}   

   phonenumber  
0          123  
1   5635888000  
2  18006708450  
3      #ERROR!  
4  12032722596  
5  18003928343  
6          NaN  
7      #ERROR!  
8          NaN  
9          NaN
```

I have tried the following code:

Solution 1:

```
mask = (df.state == '0') | (df.state == '68, Tardeo Road')
df.loc[mask, ['state']] = np.nan
```

Solution 2:

```
df.loc[(df.state == '68, Tardeo Road') | (df.state == 0), 'state'] = np.nan
```

Solution 3:

```
df.loc[df.state == '0', 'state'] = np.nan
df.loc[df.state == '68, Tardeo Road', 'state'] = np.nan
```

All of them works, but if I apply them to multiple columns, it's a little bit long.

Just wondering if it's possible to make it more concise and efficient? By using `str.replace` for example. Thanks.

Comment: It should be `|` not `&`. How can a value be `0` and `68...` at the same time?

Comment: Thanks, after retested, all of three solutions works. But if it possible to make it more concise? Especially when we have many colums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a replace:

```
df = df.replace({'state':['68, Tardeo Road','0'],
                 'dept':['567'],
                 'phonenumber':['#ERROR!','123']}, np.nan)
```

Output:

```
      id                                state                          dept    phonenumber
--  ----  -----------------------------------  ----------------------------  -------------
0   1     Abu Dhabi                            {Marketing}                             nan
1   2     MO                                   {Other}                          5635888000
2   3     nan                                  {"Human Resources"}             18006708450
3   4     National Capital Territory of Delhi  {"Human Resources"}                     nan
4   5     Aargau Canton                        {Marketing}                     12032722596
5   6     Aargau Canton                        nan                             18003928343
6   18    NB                                   {"Finance & Administration"}            nan
7   19    nan                                  {Sales}                                 nan
8   20    Abu Dhabi                            {"Human Resources"}                     nan
9   21    Aargau                               {"Finance & Administration"}            nan
```